# Can I enable the Firefox developer tools network panels to show local request as chrome?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

While using Firefox network panel I noticed that it shows only "http://" requests in its panel whereas chrome shows all (images, css, js,....).
Is there any way to enable local requests monitoring in Firefox network panel..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible, and is being tracked in [Bug 1000540](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1000540).

For local testing, consider working around this bug by running a local HTTP server. If you have Python installed, you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to serve the current directory over port 8000.

Comment: It works on local server.
But why this chrome shows it without local server and not Firefox?

Comment: See Bug 1000540 for why this doesn't work. TL:DR; In Firefox, file and network access go through very different code paths, and the network monitor only monitors the network path.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, this is `python3 -m http.server`